# How to lookback on previous indicator values and how to prevent live bar repainting?

Tags: pine-script

I'm new to pinescript so please bear with me.
I'm looking for a way to prevent repainting on a live candle. Maybe if values are only presented on bar close could prevent this but i don't know how to put it.

I've also tried to compare newest pivot value to previous pivot value but i only found a lookback for bars and not values.

Could someone help me out? Thanks in advance.

```
gr="LENGTH LEFT / RIGHT"
leftLenH = input.int(title="Pivot High", defval=10, minval=1, inline="Pivot High",group=gr)
rightLenH = input.int(title="/", defval=10, minval=1, inline="Pivot High",group=gr)
colorH = input(title="", defval=#E3EFFD, inline="Pivot High",group=gr)

leftLenL = input.int(title="Pivot Low", defval=10, minval=1, inline="Pivot Low", group=gr)
rightLenL = input.int(title="/", defval=10, minval=1, inline="Pivot Low",group=gr)
colorL = input(title="", defval=#E3EFFD, inline="Pivot Low",group=gr)

ph = ta.pivothigh(leftLenH, rightLenH)
pl = ta.pivotlow(leftLenL, rightLenL)

pivotTrendHH = ph > ph[1] ? "Bullish" : "Bearish"
pivotTrendLL = pl > pl[1] ? "Bullish" : "Bearish"
```

Answer (score 1):

To look back for values you need to save them to a **var** variable. With a **var** variable, you can save data without it being erased at the next bar.

```
var float last_ph = na
var float last_pl = na
```

I made this script that plots a label on the pivot point. And it changes the text if it is "bullish" or "bearish".
[image: ploting Bearish and Bullish on TradingView]

All Code:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at 

https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © CanYouCatchMe

//@version=5
indicator("My Script", overlay=true)
gr="LENGTH LEFT / RIGHT"
leftLenH = input.int(title="Pivot High", defval=10, minval=1, inline="Pivot High",group=gr)
rightLenH = input.int(title="/", defval=10, minval=1, inline="Pivot High",group=gr)
colorH = input(title="", defval=#E3EFFD, inline="Pivot High",group=gr)

leftLenL = input.int(title="Pivot Low", defval=10, minval=1, inline="Pivot Low", group=gr)
rightLenL = input.int(title="/", defval=10, minval=1, inline="Pivot Low",group=gr)
colorL = input(title="", defval=#E3EFFD, inline="Pivot Low",group=gr)

ph = ta.pivothigh(leftLenH, rightLenH)
pl = ta.pivotlow(leftLenL, rightLenL)
var float last_ph = na
var float last_pl = na

pivotTrendHH = ph > last_ph ? "Bullish" : "Bearish"
pivotTrendLL = pl > last_pl ? "Bullish" : "Bearish"

ph_color = ph > last_ph ? color.green : color.red
pl_color = pl > last_pl ? color.green : color.red

if (ph) //If x days ago was a pivot point
    label.new(bar_index-leftLenH, ph, pivotTrendHH, yloc=yloc.price, color=ph_color) //NOTE: bar_index-prd, becuse it occured x days ago
    last_ph := ph //Saves price data
if (pl)
    label.new(bar_index-leftLenL, pl, pivotTrendLL, yloc=yloc.price, color=pl_color)
    last_pl := pl //Saves price data
    
plotchar(ph, "ph", "", location = location.top)
plotchar(last_pl, "last_pl", "", location = location.top)
```

Comment: Wow this helps a lot!

Comment: Hello,
While visuals work perfect with you code, i've noticed that the script doesn't recognise the pivot points if the pivot points are >10 bars in the past.
How do i search for the latest HH (Bullish/Bearish) if it's 40 bars in the past?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using a boolean variable to represent your pivot which will allow you to use `ta.valuewhen()` to obtain the values you need.

To avoid repainting you can use the built in `barstate.isconfirmed` which will only be true on the last update of the candle.

```
// condition for a simple 3 bar pivot high
pvh = high < high[1] and high[1] > high[2]


pvh_high0 = ta.valuewhen(pvh, high[1], 0) // the high of the most recent pivot high
pvh_high1 = ta.valuewhen(pvh, high[1], 1) the high of the second most recent pivot high

bullish = barstate.isconfirmed and pvh and pvh_high0 > pvh_high1

plotshape(bullish, location = location.abovebar, style = shape.triangledown, color = color.lime, offset = -1)
```